# rest post request with chilkat lib

Tags: c++, rest, post, access-token, chilkat

a working post request with postman interface is not working when trying to implement in c++ with chilkat library, with postman I get response 200, with the program i get 401 (unauthorized). 
I'm using chilkat's example for rest post request.

wherever you see username and password, valid values are filled.

CkRest rest;

```
//  Make the initial connection (without sending a request yet).
bool bTls = true;
int port = 443;
bool bAutoReconnect = true;
success = rest.Connect("https://dev-182721.oktapreview.com",port,bTls,bAutoReconnect);
if (success != true) {
    std::cout << rest.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";
    return;
}
rest.put_Authorization("username:password");
rest.authorization();

rest.AddHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

//  Provide query params.
rest.AddQueryParam("grant_type","password");
rest.AddQueryParam("redirect_uri","http://localhost");
rest.AddQueryParam("username","username");
rest.AddQueryParam("password","password");
rest.AddQueryParam("scope","openid");


const char *responseStr= 
rest.fullRequestFormUrlEncoded("POST","/oauth2/default/v1/token");

if (rest.get_LastMethodSuccess() != true) {
    std::cout << rest.lastErrorText() << "\r\n";
    return;
}

//  When successful, the response status code will equal 200.
```

can anyone please help me figure out what's missing

Answer (score 0):

Okta access token examples are available here:  https://www.example-code.com/cpp/okta_oauth_oidc.asp